# Can two or more SharePoint sites be linked?

Tags: 2013, 2016

I have multiple departments with their own SharePoint sites that track performance metrics. I need to create a single site that shows information from all the sites collected in one place with dynamic features to show current data. Can i create a site that has only read capability that links to all the individual dept sites and shows any changes reflected on individual dept without having to actually go to the individual dept sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of `Cross Site Publishing` in you scenario. Using cross site publishing you can share following types of content:

**List**
**Libraries**

But you need to plan for cross site publishing. [Follow this MSDN article to learn more about the concept](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883.aspx).

Comment: would this linking be direct linking where if you edit something in the published page, even the author pages get edited?

Comment: i checked on this but it needs the authoring sites to be site collections. in my case they are standalone sites so I cant turn on the cross site publishing feature that's needed. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What are the contents you want to sync? Documents, ListItems, PublishingPages, SitePages, Assets or something else? Also are you using SP online or SP on-prem?